# C++ References vs pointers for variable inside for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, reference

Can I use a reference variable for `c` (e.g., `Customer &c`) instead?  If so how? And is this preferable to using a pointer variable?

```
    for(std::vector<Customer*>::const_iterator it = customers_.begin();
        it != customers_.end() ; it ++)
    {
        Customer *c = (*it);
        c->PrintName();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use the iterator directly? it->PrintName();

Comment: @Ferruccio: Because the iterator refers to a pointer, not an object. You would have to do `(*it)->`

Comment: Do note that while pointers can be in invalid or empty state (i.e. they are null-pointers), references cannot. Of course it doesn't seem to be the case as you aren't performing any checks in your own code either, but a vector to pointers doesn't actually convey a promise over it's contents. If it were a vector of objects you could be sure they all *are* valid objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
for(std::vector<Customer*>::const_iterator it = customers_.begin();
    it != customers_.end() ; it ++)
{
    Customer &c = *(*it);
    c.PrintName();
    ...
}
```

(The parentheses aren't necessary, but may make it clearer.)

Comment: It should be `const Customer &c`, I think, for `it` is `const_iterator`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: No, it is the `pointee` which is const. Also, think what if `customers` is `const vector<Customer> &`.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
for(std::vector<Customer*>::const_iterator it = customers_.begin();
    it != customers_.end() ; it ++)
{
    Customer const &c = **it;
    c.PrintName();
    ...
}
```

You probably don't want to do that though. Chances are pretty good that `customers_` should be a `vector<Customer>` instead of `vector<Customer *>`, and instead of calling its `PrintName` member, you should overload `operator<<` for `Customer`. Having done that, you'll be able to use something like:

```
std::copy(customers_.begin(), customers.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<Customer>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: +1 Good point.  I've gone through much of my code and converted from reference semantics to value semantics.  The particular code I'm looking at I'm not sure if that will be possible but I'll keep it in mind.  Also starting to learn the use of algorithms although it's not always immediately apparent whether they help or hurt readability.

Comment: @User: In C++03, that's *often* debatable (especially invoking a member function from `for_each` vs. using an explicit loop). In C++11, I've *rarely* seen a situation where an algorithm didn't work out better (and I suspect once I know lambdas and such better, even though rare holdouts may well disappear).

Comment: Does the `const` you added to the reference variable make it impossible to call non-const methods of Customer?  If so this is different behavior than my original code, although I may be able to use this fact in other loops.